# Error deploying jsf application in JBoss 5.1

Tags: jsf, jboss5.x

I have a big problem when I deploy my application in jboss 5.1. When it starts, I get this:

```
org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: It appears the JSP version of the container is older than 2.1 and unable to locate the EL RI expression factory, com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.  If not using JSP or the EL RI, make sure the context initialization parameter, com.sun.faces.expressionFactory, is properly set.
```

I read many things about this bug, and nothing works for me.

I haven't jsf-api and jsf-impl in my WEB-INF/lib.

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>Personnes-Front</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Mojarra JSF -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:net/blog/dev/front/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>
        <param-value>100000</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- JSF -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Facelets -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
        <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- JSF -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- FILTERS -->
    <!-- RichFaces -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Page par défaut -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>private/personnesList.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I don't understand what is the problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you elaborate on how are you deploying your application, are you using jsf present in jboss using jsf.deployer?

Comment: I use maven to build my war and I have a scope provided for jsf-api and impl so they are not in the final war. Next, I put my war in the deploy directory and run the run.sh script to run the server.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

Jboss 5.1 come with JSF 1.2.12 and this version seem to not work with jboss el.

So I have added this in my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
      <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And in my pom.xml, I fixe a newer version (1.2.13 for exemple) for jsf-api and jsf-impl and I remove the scope provided.

The war is deploy with this own jsf version and all work fine.